# Genetic Algorithm - Grouping people: Only find solutions containing criteria X,Y and Z

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to solve the following problem:

- I have a list of 30 people.
- These people need to be divided into groups of 6.
- Each person has given the names of 3 other people who they would like to be in a group with.

I thought of solving this problem using a genetic algorithm.
The fitness function could evaluate all the groups, and assign a fitness score based on how many people per room have all their preferences met. (or a scoring system similar to that)

Example:
One of the generated solutions is: 1,3,19,5,22,2,7,8,11,12,13,14,15,13,17....etc 
I would assume the first 5 people are in the first group, and the next 5 in the the next group and calculate a fitness value from that.

I think that this solution would work - does anyone see a better way of doing this?

My main question is this:
If I want to make sure person A and B are definitely in the same group, I could implement the fitness function to check for this and assign a terrible fitness if this condition isn't met. Is this the best way to do it? It seems quite inefficient. 
Is there a way to 'lock' certain parts of the solution ("certain genes") and just solve or the remainder?

Any help or insights will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
AK

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify a bit, your problem isn't about genetic programming but genetic algorithms, which are two different things. Genetic programming is about generating (using evolutionary algorithms) executable individuals that will generate your solutions while genetic algorithms individuals represent directly your solutions.

That being said, your two assumptions are corrects. Data representation is a key element of evolutionary algorithms in general and a bad representation may hinder efficient solution space exploration. Your current data representation seems correct to me, given groups are only allowed to have exactly 5 individuals. Your second thought about the way to enforce some criteria is also right. Putting a large fitness value (preferably one that can't represent a potentially valid even if bad solution) such as infinity (if your library / language allows it easily) is the preferred way to express invalid solutions in literature. This has multiple advantages over simply deleting invalid individuals: During the selection stage, bad individuals won't be selected and thus the solution space they represent won't be explored as much as interesting ones, which is computationally good because it surely won't contain optimal solutions. Knowing a solution is bad is good knowledge, after all. At the same time, genetic diversity is really important in evolutionary algorithms in order to avoid stagnation. At least some bad individual should be kept for the sake of genetic diversity in order to explore solution spaces between currently represented zones.

The goal of genetic algorithms is to compute solutions that are either impossible or too hard to compute analytically or by brute-force. Trying to dynamically lock down some genes with heuristics would require much knowledge about the inner working of your problems as well as the underlying evolution mechanisms and would be defeating the purpose of using evolutionary algorithms. The effective goal of evolutionary algorithms *is* to lock down genes that seems correct.

In fact, if you are *a priori* absolutely positively certain that some given genes must have a given value, don't represent them in your individuals. For instance, make your first group 3 individuals long if you are sure that the 2 others must be of some given value. You can then code your evaluation function as if there was 5 individuals in the first group but won't be evolving / searching to replace the 2 fixed ones.

Answer (score 0):

What does your crossover operation look like? The way you have it laid out in your description, I'm not sure how you implement it cleanly. For instance if you have two solutions:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....., 30

and

1, 2, 30, 29,......,10

Assuming you're using single point crossover function, you would have the potential to get multiple assignments for the same people and other people not being assigned at all using the genomes above.

I would have a genome with 30 values, where each value defines a person's group assignment (1-6). It would look like 656324113255632....etc. So person 1 is assigned group 6, person 2 group 5, etc. This would make the crossover operation easier to implement, because you don't have to ensure that after crossover each new solution is a valid assignment regardless of whether it's optimal.

The fitness function would assign a penalty for each group not having the proper number of members (5), and additional penalties for group member assignments that are suboptimal. I would make the first penalty significantly larger than the second, and then adjust these to get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What is the difference between having the wrong number of people per group, or having not all people in the solution? Both of these are unacceptable solutions and would need to be checked for in the fitness function and penalised? Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps in error, I assumed you wanted the size of the groups to be equal. The wrong number of people in the group would refer to the situation where a genome doesn't assign exactly five people to every group.

Comment: I also assumed that everyone is assigned to a group. If your genome is an list of person id's, the question becomes how does your crossover operation work. Lets say you have only 10 people to illustrate this so two possible solutions would be 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10   

and

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

If the crossover operation swaps genome components around the mid point I could get two new genomes

1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1

and 

10 9 8 7 6 6 7 8 9 10

which aren't valid if everyone is assigned a group and shouldn't be allowed. If the assumption is incorrect, then there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: In conclusion to my last comment, GA's assume every solution generated, whether through random population, mutation, or crossover, is a valid solution. It just might not be optimal. The other item not discussed above would ask about your mutation operator. Anyway, hopefully this is a useful discussion. Good luck.

Comment: The groups sizes are supposed to be fixed. If I use your system for mapping the genome to the group that each person is in, I would still have problem with the crossover. Assuming I have 1,2,3,4,5 and 5,4,3,2,1 - I could be left with an invalid solution of too many people per group.

Comment: I am going to be coding it in java, and I have looked at various frameworks - some provide a method of generating genomes with no repetition. I have also been looking at solutions to the Travelling Salesman Problem, since that problem also requires genomes with no repetition and involves the same issues with the crossover.

Answer (score 0):

This can be modeled as a generalized quadratic assignment problem (GQAP). This problem allows to specify a number of equipment (people) that demand a certain capacity, a number of locations (groups) that offer a capacity and the weights matrix that specifies the closeness between equipment and the distance matrix specifying the distance between locations. Additionally, there are install costs, but these are not required for your problem. I have implemented this problem in [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com). It's not part of the trunk, but I can send you the plugin if you're interested (or you compile it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the most challenging part of using a genetic algorithm for this problem is implementing the crossover.  Here's how I would do it:

First choose a constant, C.  C will stay constant throughout all generations, and I will explain it's purpose in a moment.

I will use a smaller example than 5 groups of 6 to demonstrate this crossover, but the premise is the same.  Say we have 2 parents, each consisting of 3 groups of 3.  Let's make one [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], and the other [[9,4,3],[5,7,8],[6,1,2]].

1. Make a list of possible numbers (1 through total number of people), in this case it is simply [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].  Remove 1 random number from the list.  Let's say we remove 2.  The list becomes [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
2. We assign each remaining number a probability.  The probability starts at 1, and goes up by C for any matches with the parents.  For example, in parent 1, 3 and 2 are in the same group so 3 would have a probability of 1+C.  Same thing with 6 because it forms a match in parent 2.  1 would have a probability of 1+2C, because it is in the same group as 2 in both parents.  Based on these probabilities, use a roulette wheel type selection.  Let's say we pick 6.
3. Now, we have 2 and 6 in the same group.  We similarly look for matches with these numbers and make probabilities.  For each parent, we add C if it matches with only 2 or only 6, and 2C if it matches with both.  Continue this until the group is done (for 3x3 this is the last selection, but for 5x6 there would be a few more)

   4.Choose a new random number that has not been picked and continue for other groups

One of the good things about this crossover, is that it basically includes mutations already.  There are chances built in to group people that were not grouped in their parents

Credit: [I adapted the idea from the Omicron Genetic Algorithm](http://www.cnc.una.py/cms/invest/download.php?id=199695,86,1)